# how to emit mongoose event findOneAndUpdate in angular-fullstack?

Tags: mongoose, socket.io, angular-fullstack

Angular-fullstack emits document.post('save'); out of the box . Now im trying to listen to an findOneAndUpdate but dont know how to do this i cannot find the event mongoose triggers which could be listened and emitted accordingly.

Comment: had same issue here...

Answer (score 3):

You need to register your hook before compiling the model (i.e. calling `.model()`).

From [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html):

> The `.model()` function makes a copy of schema. Make sure that you've added everything you want to schema before calling `.model()`!

I'd suggest that you export your schema as a module, register hooks on it and call `.model()` afterwards.